# SVN: Get diff for files that do not exist in those revisions (added or deleted)

Tags: svn, version-control, diff

I have a small problem with svn diff. I really have to use this line:

```
svn diff -r X:Y path/to/file.ext
```

This works perfect for cases file.ext exists in both revisions. 
The problem is when it does not - i get the message:

> Unable to find repository location for file.ext in X revision

Instead of that I would like to get a diff string like they all the lines were added/deleted (something like i would get with mercurial diff)...

Is there any way to perform that in SVN? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I found out this was not possible so I parsed the error and did the diff programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain you cannot diff directory structure changes at the file level.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that this file didn't exist in revision *X* of your repository.

Now, you might see a file `path/to/file.ext` in revision *X*, and to your mere mortal eyes, it looks like the same file. However, Subversion realizes that although the file might have the same name, it might not be the exact file. For example, if someone deleted the file in a later version, then added that file back in, the file will have the same name and directory, but it won't be the earlier version of the file.

You have to do is specify the [peg](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) revision in a URL. Let's say you're trying to compare revision 1001 and 2004:

```
 $ svn diff http://server/svn/path/to/file.ext@1001 \
     http://server/svn/path/to/file.ext@2004
```

This will do a diff of whatever file was at `http://server/svn/path/to/file.ext` at revision 1001 and 2004 -- even if they're not, according to Subversion, the same file.

Comment: Peg does not work for me, I really need the case where i could get diff between an empty string and a full file. Guess that I am going to have to parse the error and see if it comes up to do the unified diff myself... Thank you anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

Svn diff will show diff within the file.
if however you want to see what changes were made to directory structure
`svn st` is what you should be using.

EX:

```
D:\FZPCppwc>svn st
M       aam\dm\adaptor\Aal2AlarmReporter.C
!       aam\stacks\sscop\Sscop2.H
!       aam\stacks\sscop\Stc.cpp
A       aam\stacks\sscop\Test.cpp
```

So I have modified one file and deleted two files and added one file.